# Indexing HSQLDB?

Tags: hsqldb

"How to index an HSQL database?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't index a database, you create indexes on fields in a table.  You can create an index on a single column, or a single index on multiple columns.

Start here
http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#create_index-section

there is a command for that.

You should also read

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch02.html#N1030E

the section about indexes and query speed.

Comment: thanks, ofcourse what i meant by that was index on a column. Sorry for phrasing that wrongly. :D